# Can I do security trimming on search results from SharePoint 2010 against WSS 2.0

Tags: 2010, search, security-trimming, wss-2.0

I have indexed an old WSS 2.0 from my SP2010 search engine. The indexation works fine as I can see documents from the WSS 2.0 server in the results. The problem is that there doesn't seem to be any security trimming done on these results. I can see documents coming from paths I don't have access to. When I click on these documents from the results I have an expected "access denied".

I was expecting that these results don't appear at all in the results list. Is there something I'm missing ?
Do I need to implement [custom security trimming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee819923.aspx) ?

I have read this [forum](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointsearch/thread/a58fbc34-e784-4319-a59f-02849938cc21) and it looks like security trimming works out-of-the-box from WSS 2.0 to WSS 3.0. Maybe it doesn't work from WSS 2.0 to SP2010 ?

I tried indexing a shared folder on the network and the security trimming is correctly applied.

Answer (score 2):

The SharePoint 2010 search index, while crawling, collects and stores the information about access control list (ACL) defined for the files or documents. While searching, this information is being used by the search service to security trim the results and so the search results are displayed according to user permissions.

Since WSS 2.0 does not support item or folder level permissions, ACLs are not found at crawl time. And so, you cannot have out-of-box security trimming.

The solution is to build custom security trimmer implementing ISecurityTrimmer2 interface.

By the way, I already built trimmers for such cases and I [wrote a blog post here](http://extreme-sharepoint.com/2011/10/12/security-trimming-sharepoint-2010-isecuritytrimmer2/) which focuses on building custom security trimmers when the content to be crawled is an external site.... like WSS 2.0.

Comment: The logic you may apply in the above example to trim results for WSS 2 pages is 1) Grab the documentcrawlUrl in CheckAccess() 2) Invoke a httprequest for the documentcrawlUrl which is a WSS 2.0 page. If you get access-denied for the user, return false in bitArray[x].  Please be aware of the performance implications if the request take long time because of slow network.